# Microsoft Access Combo Box Arrow Hidden Rectangle Reappears

Tags: forms, ms-access, combobox, dropdown

I have a combo box on a continuous form.  I don't want the arrow on the combo box to show unless the record is being changed.  I accomplished this by placing a rectangle over the combo box arrow.  This works great because it hides the arrow until the record is clicked, then the arrow shows.

The problem is that if you save the form design, close the form, and then open the form, the arrow will reappear and "stick" as you mouse over it.  See image below.

The strange thing is that if you open the form, go into design view, and then go back to form view, it no longer "sticks".

Has anyone else had this problem, and if so have you found a work-around?

[image]

Comment: I just tested this and cannot replicate issue.

Comment: @June7 I did more testing and it turns out there was a little "sliver" of the combobox arrow button peaking out from behind the rectangle.  When I expanded the rectangle to cover the entire arrow button, I no longer experienced this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I did more testing and it turns out there was a little "sliver" of the combobox arrow button peaking out from behind the rectangle. When I expanded the rectangle to cover the entire arrow button, I no longer experienced this problem.

Comment: Yep, replicated that. Have to mouse over the "sliver" except record that has focus, arrow will hide when record loses focus.